# Printwriter stucks when calling print method

Tags: java, printing, client, printwriter

This is a Thread, which handles input and output from the serverside:

```
    public void run() {
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (!currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
            SocketChannel socketChannel = null;
            try {
                socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                readFromSocket(socketChannel);
            } catch (ClosedByInterruptException e) {
                // closed due to interrupt
                connected = false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (!isInterrupted()) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                connected = false;
            } finally {
                quietClose(socketChannel);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads an message from socketChannel and executes
     * {@link AbstractServer#handleMessage(String)}. Initializes
     * {@link #writer} with the socketChannel.
     * 
     * @param socketChannel
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void readFromSocket(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
        reader = null;
        writer = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketChannel.socket().getInputStream()));

            if (writer == null) {
                writer = new PrintWriter(socketChannel.socket().getOutputStream(), true);
            }
            String message;
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                handleMessage(message);
            }
        } catch (ClosedByInterruptException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            quietClose(reader);
            quietClose(writer);
        }
    }
```

If i call the print-method the thread is getting stucked. Which means the "before" is printed, but the "after" is never reached.
The CheckError method of the printwriter returns false!

```
    /**
     * Sends a message to the client.
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    public void sendMessage(final String message) {
        System.out.println("before");
        writer.print(message);
        System.out.println("after");
        writer.flush();
    }
```

It is in an AbstractServer which is used by two different Servers. The first one was used before already and always worked without a problem (and still does).
The other one is new and causes this problem. It is definitly only one writer for every connection (both localhost with different ports) initialized.

The Client side Datafetcher looks like this:

```
protected void fetchDataFromSocket() {
    if (socketDataFetcher != null) {
        socketDataFetcher.interrupt();
    }

    socketDataFetcher = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    String message = socketConnection.readLine();
                    if (messageHandler != null) {
                        messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    socketDataFetcher.start();
}
```

Its also pretty much the same as the other one that works with only little changes which actually can't cause the problem.
What could be the reason that the printwriter behaves like this?

edit: If i don't start the socketDataFetcher on the client side, the printwriter is not getting stucked!

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see the declarations, the reader and writer objects (referenced in the readFromSocket() method) look like they might be member variables. I would be concerned about the reader and writer not being thread-safe. I would see about about removing these member variables and see if you still have issues with the writer.

Comment: Hi, yes it both are member variables.  But the writer is called only in this two methods (datafetcher only to initialize and sendMessage). In the sendMessage i added "synchronized (writer)" now, even though it shouldnt be possibly that two different threads call the method. So thread safety can't be the problem, right?